# Unable to set height of a div with class

Tags: jquery, ios, css, swift, uiwebview

In my iOS app, I am opening an URL in `UIWebView`. I want to change the `top` of the `div` with `class="main-container scrollable"`. I am not expert in `jQuery`. The source of the page has,

```
<head></head>
<body class="scope" controller="MainCtrl"
    <div class="scope toast-top-right" id="toast-container"></div>
    <div class="app-container">
        <div id="left-panel" class="slide-panel” ui-view="leftPanel"></div>
        <div id="main-panel" class="partial-container">
            <div class="scope" ui-view="navbar"></div>
            <div class="scope" ui-view="mainPanel">
                <div class="page-home scope">
                    <div class="main-container scrollable"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I tried,

```
webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("$('.partial-container').children().eq(1).find('.main-container').css('top', '0')")
```

also tried,

```
webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("$('.partial-container').children().eq(1).find('.main-container').offset('top', '0')")
```

But not successful.

I could able to get the `top` by

```
webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("alert($('.partial-container').children().eq(1).find('.main-container').offset().top)")
```

which returns me `'48'`. I want to set it to `'0'`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did that using `"$('#main-panel').find('.main-container').attr('style', 'top:0px !important;')"`

Answer (score 0):

in order for 'top' value to be changed, you need to set the positioning of your element to something rather than 'static' which is the default positioning. this will work with you:

```
webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("$('.partial-container').children().eq(1).find('.main-container').css({'position' : 'absolute','top' : '0px'})");
```

you can change 'absolute' to whatever positioning you may want.